# I want to removing highlighted braces in vim

Tags: macos, vim

[image: here's the image!]

```
" Configuration file for vim

set modelines=0     
" CVE-2007-2438

" Normally we use vim-extensions. If you want true vi-compatibility
" remove change the following statements
set nocompatible    
" Use Vim defaults instead of 100% vi compatibility
set backspace=2     
" more powerful backspacing

" Don't write backup file if vim is being called by "crontab -e"
au BufWrite /private/tmp/crontab.* set nowritebackup nobackup
" Don't write backup file if vim is being called by "chpass"
au BufWrite /private/etc/pw.* set nowritebackup nobackup

syntax on        
set ai           
set shiftwidth=4 
set tabstop=4

set ruler         
set backspace=2   
set ic          
set hlsearch     
set incsearch    
set smartindent  
set confirm      
set history=200  
set cursorline   
set number       
:nohl
:set nowrap      
set mouse=a
colo google
hi Normal ctermbg=none
```

the above is my .vimrc

As you can see, my braces was highlighted at line 3 and line 5 although my cursor is not on them(so, the highlighting may not be controlled by MatchParen).

However, while I can't remove their highlighting by using MatchParen, I think there must be another way to deal with it.

How can I disable these highlighting???

thx :)

Comment: Could a plugin be causing this? I can't reproduce this. Or can you post (the relevant parts of) your `.vimrc`?

Comment: https://github.com/google/vim-colorscheme-primary/tree/master/colors    <<<here's the colorscheme

Comment: @L3viatha - i have post my .vimrc then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

Comment: Thanks for ur solution, but i don't know how to use SyntaxAttr.vim here. I put it in the folder .vim/autoload/  , and then i don't  know what to do next. Can u tell me??

Comment: Put the cursor on one of the `{` that are highlighted in red. Then `:call SyntaxAttr#SyntaxAttr()` (or define a mapping for that, and invoke that). The plugin will tell you the syntax group and mapping to highlighting.

Comment: still doesn't work, but i think i will try tomorrow thx a lot